# How to animate a cylindrical dial on iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, cocoa-touch, swipe

I am building an iOS app and I have a button-like view where the user can change the value by hold-swiping left or right:

[image]

The user can change the numbers by touching/holding down their finger, and swiping left and right. This works perfect and many people got used to using it quickly. However, some people couldn't initially figure out how to implement such functionality, and I want to implement a dial effect below it:

[image]

It is just a quick Photoshop sketch, it doesn't look well but you get the idea. How can I make the dial turn naturally? By "naturally", I mean that the dial will move left and right when the user swipes, and the leftmost/rightmost edges will get smaller/thinner just as if the dial was a physical, cylindrical dial (as in SLR cameras at the top to set the shooting mode, or the vertical equivalent would be something like the date selector, especially the pre-iOS 7 one). I want to achieve this natural dialing effect but even though I thought a lot, I couldn't find where to start. Is there any easy way to achieve that, and if yes, how? If no, are there any alternatives to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: Look at placing an appropriate CATransform3D into the layer property of CALayer